# Internal Rewrite in Nginx not work, and redirected

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Hi I want a rewrite rule, but i don't want to redirect it, and requesting one URL but load different content from another URL.  So, I think last and break flag in rewrite directive is a good solution. But, it's always redirected, I search the problem and they state that if the new URL not from nginx instance it will redirect instead. Here several lines of my config:

```
...
rewrite ^(/\w+/$)(.+\.php) /$2 last;
proxy_pass upstream_name:80;
...
```

What i ask is how i can use rewrite but not redirected?

Update: 
For example, i want to make a new like /link/asd, but there is no /link/asd in my web application. I want my /link/asd link load resource from /asd link. then, i think the rewrite last flag is a good solution. If my understanding is false, please correct me and explain it. Thank you

Comment: That `rewrite` statement is not generating the redirect.

Comment: @RichardSmith yeah it shoud not redirect. But, its actually redirected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite exactly `/link/example` to `/example`, where `example` is anything, you can use this `rewrite`:

```
rewrite ^/link/(.+)$ /$1 last;
```

This will also match `/link/example/something/else`, as the `.+` matches any characters before the end of the string (`$`). If you want to restrict which characters are allowed in the capture group, for example, exclude `/` from the capture group, one can use `[^/]+` notation for the regex.

Comment: I already use that similar rewrite configuration for instance level and it works. Although, when i use the configuration in reverse proxy level it didn't  work. Are you know why?

Comment: Please add the configuration file in your question about your attempt. Please include the complete `server` block.